# Confusion around change of variable summand proof representation theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I was looking at a proof in a course on representation theory where they constructed a $G$-morphism ($G$ a group). Consider $V$ and $W$ both $G$-representations, $W$ a subrepresentation of $V$. Now consider $\pi$ : $V$ $\rightarrow$ $W$ a linear map defined as : $\pi(v) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{h \in G} h.\pi_1(h^{-1}.v)$ , here $\pi_1$ is the linear projection of $V$ onto $W$. Now they try to prove that this map is a $G$-morphism. So they say $\pi(g.v) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{h \in G} h.\pi_1(h^{-1}(g.v)) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{h' = g^{-1}h \in G} gh'.\pi_1(h'^{-1}.v) = g\pi(v)$.

So now were are not summing over $h$, but instead over $h'$ ? What difference does this make ? By my understanding saying $h \in G$ or saying $h' \in G$ at the summand just means we iterate over every element in the group, $h$ is just a letter and does not refer to a specific element in the group. So how can we sum over $g^{-1}h$ ?

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: The old sum is over the elements of $G$, and so is the new sum. The formula $h' = g^{-1} h$ is showing how the old summation dummy variable $h$ relates to the new one $h'$, which is by applying the bijection $G \to G$ defined by $h \mapsto g^{-1} h$.

Comment: @Joppy You mean $h' \mapsto g^{-1}h$  ?

Comment: Okay so I could also just write $\sum\limits_{h \in G}$ in the new sum ?

Comment: You wouldn't say $h'\mapsto g^{-1}h$, you would say $h'=g^{-1}h$, but yes. Also, from what you've written, you can't say $\pi_1$ is "the" projection of $V$ onto $W$, you can only say it is "a" projection. (The word "the" implies there is a unique or distinguished projection - there will be a distinguished projection though if you pick a complementary subrepresentation or $V$ is an inner product space.)